# Excel Visual Basic ADODB SQL connection string not working

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to connect to an SQL Server through Automatisation in VBA, so each time Excel starts, the SQL Statement updates the table in Excel.

Problem is, that my Connection string always throws an exception:

> "Run-time error "-2147217843 (80040e4d)'; Automation error"

I have following data provided:

- Servername, though it has a comma in it's Name
- Database Name

I also have a Windows user (accountname & Password), that I run the Statements from, but I doubt, it is necessary to provide this information to the SQL Server.

the Connection string Looks as follows:

```vb
Public Sub OpenConnection2(pServer As String, pCatalog As String)
    Dim mDataBase As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mCmd As New ADODB.Command

Call mDataBase.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=" & pCatalog & ";Data Source=" & pServer & ";")
    mCmd.ActiveConnection = mDataBase
End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIR  "Automation error" - indicates problems on stage of creating COM-object. So your connection string itself maybe OK. Problem could be in registred/not-registred OLEDB-providers

Comment: To  connection with Windows authentication, add ";Integrated Security=SSPI"  to the connection string so the current Windows account is used. No need to specify a user/password. You mentioned servername has a comma - do you mean the a comma followed by a port number?

Comment: Ok I understand. I'm going to look into the OLEDB-Providers, and I added the Integrated Security=SSPI. Still not working though 
The Server Name is something like a whole number itself. Ist like this:
"asdf15789,456" So yes, ist a Number and a certain port

Comment: It's definitely the connectionstring, I commented everything out, except of the con.Open ConnectionString, and the Error still persists

Answer (score 0):

As you, FunnyO, already stated, it is the connection string.
You probably do not have the correct driver definition.

Try something like that:
strCnn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=" & pServer & ";Database=" & pCatalog & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Sure, a very simple connection string. But it should work out as it is a very common one...